# How to download offline maps from Google Maps, I need format big planet sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, maps

I want to use maps offline for an application that is not going to connect to Internet. So I need the sqlite files of the maps for some cities and areas. I am trying to do it with Atlas Mobile Creator, but it seems I have trouble to connect this program through a proxy.

Some body can help me and tell me how can I download maps offline to use it in my application ???

Any help would be really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance,
Ariel

Answer (score 1):

ariel,I have no idea about atlas mobile creator but recently I developed an application in which I used maps.With that knowledge I could say-----when you use google maps in your application we direct our map data to store in device sd card.What happens with this approach is ,when first time our app is started maps are loaded based on our specified location parameters and are stored in sd card.so ,next time same data is retrieved from our memory card.only for the first time you are supposed to have internet.same stored data is retrieved over and over again.here is the code to get started.

mention these permissions in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

below the uses sdk.Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what I need is to have and access the maps from local files in the cache will not work because it can be deleted, that's why I need a way to download the maps in files, my app is not going to have access to Internet. Any idea ?